# Lock the display of windows 10 workstation using UWP store application

Tags: c#, uwp, windows-store-apps, windows-10-universal

I'm looking for a way to prompt the windows 10 system to lock the display in order to provide more privacy by protecting it from unauthorized use. Is there any standard API for doing this in Windows Universal development? Or alternatively to simulate Keyboard for sending <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd> combination.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I understand you probably want to do this for good intentions, but such functionality is not available via any APIs in UWP. The reason for this is very likely the fact that giving an app the ability to lock the PC could easily give a **malicious** app the ability to **lock the user out** of the system by launching on startup and always locking the PC anytime it is activated. The same way apps are unable to **shutdown or restart** the PC.

Furthermore, the keyboard shortcut cannot be simulated for likely the same reasons, as the <kbd>Win</kbd> key on the keyboard is in general reserved for system shortcuts and it is really not easy to override it (you have to perform really **low-level keyboard handling** like in [this example](https://github.com/shanselman/babysmash/blob/master/KeyboardHook.cs), which is again not something that will be allowed to pass Microsoft Store certification).

I would suggest assuming that the user has the auto OS lock timeout set up the way he or she likes it and that if you want to provide additional security in your app, you can add some kind of **PIN-lock mechanism** so that your app will lock itself automatically when not used for certain period of time.

Comment: Thanks for the response and as well for correcting me on the combination key. Yes, we are seeking for a standard way to improve the efficiency of our app which is currently available on Store. I thought this may not be allowed by the Microsoft Store for the same reasons you clarified.

Comment: If my answer resolved your question, please consider marking it as answer so that is solved :-) . Happy coding!

Comment: Just for the record, I'm not looking for a way to provide protection on my app using PIN-lock etc. The intention is indeed to lock the user's display in order to prevent unauthorized access to the PC. You stated this is not possible for the Store applications at least till now, so agreed!

Comment: Yes, that is true. I would rely on the user's auto-lock settings and only just for example log out of your app when not used for a longer time.

Comment: You could lock your app - show a different screen/content when locked. There are API to use Windows Hello to reactivate you app… so the computer ist running, but you app hides the content if the user wish… maybe that will work for you? => https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/security/microsoft-passport